# Вводится текст и разбивается на группы из k элементов, в которых символы переставляются некоторым образом, далее переставляются сами группы символов

Tags: python

Я написал код, который делит вводимый текст на группы по 5 символов и выводит их в обратном порядке. Но я не знаю как перемешать сами группы и вывести их. Думал создать массив в который запишутся группы, и вывести их в обратном порядке как и строки(с помощью среза [::-1]), но не получается. Помогите пожалуйста)

```py
s = str(input('Введите строку: '))
s = ''.join(s.split())
for x in range(0, len(s), 5):
    arr = s[x:x+5]
    print(arr[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
lt=[]
s = str(input('Введите строку: ')) 
s = ''.join(s.split()) 
for x in range(0, len(s), 5): 
    arr = s[x:x+5] 
    lt.append(arr)
print (lt)
random.shuffle(lt)
print(lt)
```

Искомый результат

```
Введите строку: ergbdgnbsnsynnyhsrththhzdthth
['ergbd', 'gnbsn', 'synny', 'hsrth', 'thhzd', 'thth']
['thhzd', 'synny', 'ergbd', 'gnbsn', 'hsrth', 'thth']
```